# What is the best flavor of Linux for a home file (media) server?

Tags: linux, home-server

I'd like to setup a Linux server to serve media files (video and music) to my other computers in the house.

Some requirements:

1. Has to be able to network with the
   Windows computers in the house
2. Has to be able to shut off at a certain
   time, or when I press the front
   button of the computer
3. The more  power features the better: Wake up,
   shut down mostly
4. Don't want to be entering credentials each
   time I'm trying to access files

And maybe anything else that I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to use your computer as a NAS server, why not try [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/)?

[**Wikipedia:**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeNAS#Features)

> FreeNAS is a free network-attached
>   storage server, supporting: CIFS
>   (Samba), FTP, NFS, rsync, AFP
>   protocols, iSCSI, S.M.A.R.T., local
>   user authentication, and software RAID
>   (0,1,5), with a web-based
>   configuration interface. FreeNAS takes
>   less than 64 MB once installed on
>   CompactFlash, hard drive or USB flash
>   drive. FreeNAS is currently
>   distributed as an ISO image and in
>   source form. It is possible to run
>   FreeNAS from a Live CD, with the
>   configuration files stored on an
>   MS-DOS-formatted floppy disk. There is
>   also a VMware disk image available.

If not this, I'd just use whichever flavour of linux you're comfortable with.

Comment: not Linux, but most certainly a fine solution! :)

Answer (score 4):

This all seems pretty straight-forward... any distribution should be able to do this.  Might as well pick something easy to use like [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: I use Ubuntu for my home media/music server. I've got no complaints.

Answer (score 1):

Low power consumption and noise might be a consideration. There are some interesting 'appliance-like' embedded linux servers that might be worth a look. I have one of these, which is an interesting design, and mostly works just like a debian server - http://www.excito.com